# Yii2 multiple ListView in one page

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using 2 `widgets` in one page, Both are using `listview`, one is for blogs and another one is for pages and both are using `ScrollPager`. I want to **show more** `button` in each separately. The problem is the show more button is shown only for pages but not for blog, if I remove the page widget it will display for blogs. I'm trying to display show more for pages and show more for blogs. I tried by `pageParam` but the problem still exist.

**widget**:

```
class UserPagesWidget extends \yii\base\Widget
{
    public $usr_id;

    public function run()
    {
        $dataProviderContent = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' =>  Post::find()->Where(['user_id' => $this->usr_id])
                    ->orderBy(['post_crdate' => SORT_DESC]),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageParam' => 'contentPagination',
                'pageSize' => 5,
            ],
        ]);

        return $this->render('/user/widget/pstList', [
            'dataProviderContent' => $dataProviderContent,
            ]);
    }
}
```

**Render file**:

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProviderContent,
    'summary'=>'',
    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'], // LY - FOR ( LOAD MORE )
    'emptyText' => 'No Content',
    'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                    return $this->render('/user/profileContent/usr-pst-content',['model' => $model]);
                },
    'pager' => ['class' => \kop\y2sp\ScrollPager::className()],
    ]);
?>
```

**Blog Widget**:

```
class UserBlogsWidget extends \yii\base\Widget
{
    public $usr_id;

    public function run()
    {
        $dataProviderBlog = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' =>  Blog::find()->Where(['user_id' => $this->usr_id])
                ->orderBy(['blog_update' => SORT_DESC]),
                'pagination' => [
                'pageParam' => 'blogPagination',
                'pageSize' => 6,
            ],
        ]);

        return $this->render('/user/widget/blgList', [
            'dataProviderBlog' => $dataProviderBlog,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Blog render file**:

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProviderBlog,
        'summary'=>'',
        'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'], // LY - FOR ( LOAD MORE )
        'emptyText' => 'No Blogs',
        'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                        return $this->render('/user/profileContent/usr-blg-content',['model' => $model]);
                    },
        'pager' => ['class' => \kop\y2sp\ScrollPager::className()],
    ]);
?>
```

Both widgets are called in one view file.

```
<div class="row chn-row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:15px">
        <!-- separing -->
        <?= UserPagesWidget::widget(['usr_id' => $model->user_id]) ?>

        <!-- separing -->   
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:15px">
        <?= UserBlogsWidget::widget(['usr_id' => $model->user_id]) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the **show more** `button` is displayed only for pages.

Comment: Yes, The `ScrollPager` is used for infinite scrolling of the page, and not widgets, What if you use the `iframe` to load both the `ListViews` via 2 different views? I have used `ScrollPager` but never tried this approach, you might give it a try

Comment: I will try this suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust selectors to distinguish between two widgets. By default `ScrollPager` uses some generic selector (`.list-view`) that will match all list views. You should explicitly set ID for `ListView` widgets and use it in `ScrollPager` config as selector for widget initialization.

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    // ...
    'dataProvider' => $dataProviderBlog,
    'options' => ['id' => 'blog-list-view'],
    'pager' => [
        'class' => \kop\y2sp\ScrollPager::className(),
        'container' => '#blog-list-view',
        'paginationSelector' => '#blog-list-view .pagination',
    ],
]) ?>
<?= ListView::widget([
    // ...
    'dataProvider' => $dataProviderContent,
    'options' => ['id' => 'content-list-view'],
    'pager' => [
        'class' => \kop\y2sp\ScrollPager::className(),
        'container' => '#content-list-view',
        'paginationSelector' => '#content-list-view .pagination',
    ],
]) ?>
```

See https://kop.github.io/yii2-scroll-pager/#general-options